# Error when accessing webservice through proxy internet connection

Tags: c#

I have created a .net windows application ,in that i need to get information from server via webservice. if my internet connection through proxy then thrown error ERROR: Could not resolve host: ws.audioscrobbler.com; No data record of requested type .if its direct connection everything work fine.Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using a [WebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx) instance in the scenario where you need to connect through a Proxy server?

You can not simply expect to be using the same logic in the scenario where the server is behind a proxy server and the scenario where it is not. You need to allow the user to configure Proxy settings and act accordingly when a Proxy server is configured.

Comment: I tried to assign proxy with webproxy class but it gives error "Requested FTP command doesn't support when using HTTP Proxy".

Comment: How can we assign proxy settings?

can u give me the code  fot FTPwebrequest?